# Show text vertically and counter-clockwise in any table cells

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I have the following CSS and table with `choice 3` and `choice 4` vertically displayed but clockwise. I would like to show `choice 3` and `choice 4` vertically and counter-clockwise. I am not able to find style values for `text-orientation` for my need.

Note that text `choice 3` and `choice 4` are just examples, and the real texts could be quite long. I am looking for a solution that can apply to any cells in a table (and preferably center the text horizontally if a cell's space is quite wide).

```css
.rotate {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: mixed;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>choice 1</td>
    <td>choice 2</td>
    <td>total</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="rotate">choice 3</div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="rotate">choice 4</div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>total</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Update**
Here is my real table.

[image]

Here is a pic of testing `display: flex`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can add `transform: rotate(180deg);`

**A quick note**

> Internet Explorer supports different values from an earlier version of
>   the spec, which originated from SVG.

[Source](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-writing-mode)

Which `vertical-rl` is not included, therefore this  isn't going to work as expected in Internet Explorer

---

```css
.rotate {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>choice 1</td>
    <td>choice 2</td>
    <td>total</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="rotate">choice 3</div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="rotate">choice 4</div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>total</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for chiming in! I need to have a solution across browsers (including IE 10). `writing-mode: vertical-rl` is not required, as long as the solution is working across browsers. Thanks, again!

Comment: for that you might need to know the width of your word/element,

Comment: The real text is unpredictable in terms size. Computing its width makes things complicated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution would be to have class for both `<td>` and `<div>` so you can give margins and give transform which supports all browsers like this:

```css
div.rotate{
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Safari/Chrome */
 -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Firefox */
 -o-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Opera */
 -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
}

td.rotate{
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: inherit;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="1">choice 1</td>
    <td colspan="1">choice 2</td>
    <td>total</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="rotate" colspan="1">
      <div class="rotate">choice 3</div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="rotate" colspan="1">
      <div class="rotate">choice 4</div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>total</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You have have a look here for more information: https://www.broculos.net/2013/12/vertical-text-for-table-headers-with-css.html

Comment: Thanks for the info! Does td.rotate have to have the height property? In my case, the size of text is unpredicable.

Comment: You can set `height:100%` if your text is unpredictable, that will automatically set the height to whatever text height is, or you can give `padding-bottom: 40px `or any amount of pixels instead of height which also might make automatic space between your multiple `<td>`

Comment: When I set height to 100%, the vertical text extends into other cells. You can try long text.

Comment: It is not working. I updated my post with two pictures.